# .htaccess and url parameters rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to change a url like

```
http://mydomain.xx/details.php?title=Hilton+Knoxville
```

into

```
http://www.mydomain.xx/detail.php/hilton-knoxville
```

using the `.htaccess` file.

Can someone help me to write it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in your /.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /details\.php\?title=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^details.php$ /%1? [NE,NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /details.php?title=$1  [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: i need to something like this http://www.mydomain.xx/detail/hilton-knoxville .
can you tell me how to do this ?